# When app is killed service is stopped

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-service

I have created service that calls an API and gets a response. Based on the response we update status. When the app is in the foreground, the service works well but when the application is killed, the time service is stopped and doesn't get the API response.

#### What I want:

When the service starts and the API is called but the app is killed by the user before the response comes, the service should continue execution without restart and not be stopped.
Please check following code.

```
   public class Send_Service extends Service {
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new 
         Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   // my code
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    param.putAll(params);
                    return param;
                }
            };
            request.setShouldCache(false);
            // Adding request to request queue
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    60000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            mRequestQueue.add(request);

        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    }
}
  return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;}
```

**Manifest**

```
 <service android:name=".services.Sendfax_Service"
        android:enabled="false"
        />
<!--calling service-->
 Intent i = new Intent(this, Sendfax_Service.class);
 startService(i);
```

Comment: What device are you testing on? Have you tested on other devices?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with

> START_STICKY Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int):
>   if this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the
>   started state but don't retain this delivered intent.

Instead of

> START_NOT_STICKY Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int,
>   int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after
>   returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), and there are no new
>   start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the
>   started state and don't recreate until a future explicit call to
>   Context.startService(Intent).

If you want it running even when the process is killed

Comment: As per your solution service is restarted from the beginning but we want it to resume that service where it is stopped when killed app.

Comment: But is not running on all devices. Service gets killed on customised OS phone like MIUI, OPPPO, VIVO RedMi etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your service foreground. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

But for this case, better to use Job-Scheduling https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html